# I can't edit scss file (Because I can't find it)

Tags: html, css, scss-mixins

I'm editing my website, I don't know how to write code in Html, css or these things, but I know how to mess with something here and there and get what I want done. But I'm stuck for days in this scss file, most of the layout things I want to edit I simply can't because this file doesn't exist.

[image: File]

I would be very grateful if someone could help me I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file don't exists, `_grid.scss:18` is a Source Map. It is important for debugging.

Source maps are used to map your source code to your compiled code.

So, for example: `bootstrap.min.css` will show some source maps `(_grid.scss, _colors.scss ...)`

If you need to edit the css, you will need to download SCSS files, edit and then, re-build to a single css. Or you could make a custom style, patching over the library's base style.

Comment: you said "If you need to edit the css, you will need to download SCSS files, edit....." but file does not exist. Can you please clarify about how to do edit. Please also cite free resources. Thanks

Comment: @kpmrpar This is a good start point: https://www.mugo.ca/Blog/How-to-customize-Bootstrap-4-using-Sass

Comment: @kpmrpar Download bootstrap source files, edit what you need, and build it, running: sass scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss:css/bootstrap.css